# PDAL: Couldn't create filter stage of type 'crop'

Tags: python, docker, gis, gdal, osgeo

I'm trying to use pdal in python. I started with a super simple cropping:

```
json = """{
    "pipeline":[
        "ARRA-LFTNE_NewYork_2010_000636.las",
        {
            "type":"crop",
            "bounds":"([616766.770,617765.46],[4510733.640,4511649.800])"
        },
        "output.laz"
    ]
}"""

pipeline = pdal.Pipeline(unicode(json,encoding="utf-8"))
pipeline.validate() # check if our JSON and options were good
pipeline.loglevel = 8 #really noisy
count = pipeline.execute()
arrays = pipeline.arrays
metadata = pipeline.metadata
log = pipeline.log
```

The json is from pdal's hp https://www.pdal.io/pipeline.html#pipeline, and should simply crop the image. However, at the validation it fails with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/src/test.py", line 69, in <module>
    pipeline.validate() # check if our JSON and options were good
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pdal/pipeline.py", line 42, in validate
    return self.p.validate()
  File "pdal/libpdalpython.pyx", line 93, in pdal.libpdalpython.PyPipeline.validate (pdal/libpdalpython.cpp:2639)
RuntimeError: Couldn't create filter stage of type 'crop'.
```

I have tried running other small examples I found online, but I keep getting the "Couldn't create filter stage of type xx"-error!

I'm running it on a dockerfile from the image: pdal/pdal:1.5

Answer (score 0):

Look again at the site you linked. The `crop` filter ([docs here](https://www.pdal.io/stages/filters.crop.html)) uses the option `bounds`, not `dimension` to specify the bounding box. In `PDAL`, `dimension` means a dimension of the point data (X, Y, Z, Red, Green, Blue, etc).

[Dimensions docs here](https://www.pdal.io/dimensions.html)

Comment: Sorry, I must I have made a copy-paste mistake. However, with 'bounds' in stead of 'dimension' I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Your filter `type` should read `filters.crop` and not just `crop`.